# Confusion on Probability for People leaving before others.

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

I have a question from a textbook and I don't know where to start?

The textbook says that a sample solution is provided - but no solution is seen and it was a typo so I'm just lost.

The question states that there is a train with 7 stops, and there are 4 people Named A, B, C, and D. What is the probability such that A, B, and C leave at different stops with the circumstances that C leaves Before A. It is also given that A MUST leave before B.

What I'm thinking is that there are 7^4 possible outcomes as it doesn't matter where D goes.

That only leaves the "numerator" portion. My thought process was that for the numerator it would be (7C1) * (6C1) * (5C1) * 7.

Thus we get ((7C1) * (6C1) * (5C1) * 7)/(7^4)

I know I'm wrong - but if someone could show me the steps - It'd be nice.

Comment: **Hint:** 1. Ignore the  person D; 2. Try to solve it with only the first criteria (A,B,C leaves at different stops); 3. If you have the previous solution consider symmetry in the possible solutions to get what you want.

Comment: Right, but why would we ignore D? Isn't it technically a given that he must get off?

Comment: Because it doesn't matter where D gets off it won't change the outcome.

Comment: Oh! I see. Thank you! I will try doing this myself before looking at anything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore passenger D, as a non-factor.

Computation will be $$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},$$

where $D = 7^3$, which represents $7$ choices for each of $A,B,C$.

Superficially, you would expect $N = (7 \times 6 \times 5)$.  However, such a computation permits $(3!)$ ways of ordering the departures of $A,B,C$.  By the constraints of the problem, you must therefore apply a factor of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3!}$ when computing $N$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle N = \frac{7!}{(7-3)!} \times \frac{1}{3!} = \binom{7}{3}.$

Final answer:

$$\frac{\binom{7}{3}}{7^3}.$$

---

**Addendum**
Why passenger D can be ignored.

Since there is no constraint on which exit passenger D takes, his choice of exit will have no affect on the  possible ways that A,B,C can exit, either in the computation of the denominator ($D = 7^3$) or the numerator $[N = \binom{7}{3}]$.

If you do include passenger D in the computations, you would simply be multiplying both $N$ and $D$ by a factor of $(7)$, which would have no effect on the value of the fraction, $\displaystyle \frac{N}{D}$.

Answer (score 0):

To meet the condition that A, B and C leave at different stations: A can leave at 7 stations, B at 6 and C at 5.

There are 6 possible orderings, but only one is allowed. Therefore (7*6*5)/7^3/6 = 5/49.